# Task :react-native-community_masked-view:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, gradle, react-hooks

error

> Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 FAILURE: Build failed with an e
> an exception. * What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':react-native-community_masked-view:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. > Could not resolve all files conf
> for configuration ':react-native-community_masked-view:androidJdkImage'. > Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactTyrnalpe=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}. > Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: C:\Users\hp\AppDdroiata\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-34\core-for-system-modules.jar. > Error while executing process C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21\bin\jlink.exe with are-paguments {--module-path C:\Users\hp.gradle\caches\transforms-3\393400499b2af28f59d755a5f301569b\transformed\output\temp\jmod --add-modules java.base --outdle\put C:\Users\hp.gradle\caches\transforms-3\393400499b2af28f59d755a5f301569b\transformed\output\jdkImage --disable-plugin system-modules} * Try: > Run wit geth --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. > Run with --scan to get full insights. > Get mole.ore help at https://help.gradle.org. BUILD FAILED in 33s.
> info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

I was trying to build by app and this shows. i am new to app development.